# How do I put any value X after all the minimums in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, jagged-arrays

If I enter an `array` , at first the code finds the `minimums` then I want to put zeroes after all the minimums . For example
`given an array` = `1,1,3,1,1`
As we see `1s` are the minimum so the result should be = `1,0,1,0,3,1,0,1,0`

#### CODE

```
#include <pch.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{

    int min = 10000;
    int n;                                       
    std::cout << "Enter the number of elements (n): "; //no of elements in the 
    std::cin >> n;                                     //array

    int *array = new int[2 * n];
    
    std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                      
        std::cin >> array[i];
        if (array[i] > min)
            min = array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                

        if (array[i] == min) {                   // Not very clear about this
            for (int k = n; k > i; k--)          // part of the code, my teacher
                 array[k] = array[k - 1];        //explained it to me , but i 
             array[i + 1] = 0;               // didn't understand (from the      
             i++;                            // `for loop k` to be precise)
             n++;
        }
        std::cout << array[i] << ", 0";
    }
        
                                  
    
    return 0;
}
```

> But my answer doen't put zeroes exactly after minimums

Comment: `std::vector` would make this a lot easier.

Comment: we aren't into vectors yet

Comment: To find the min, replace > by <

Comment: Maybe n++ and i++ instead of i-- and n--, and after the inner loop

Comment: @Damien Yes that was `i++` I changed it by mistake . But that doesn't solve this issue

Comment: Have you corrected the 3 other mistakes that I indicated ?

Comment: I found another issue. I will post the code

Comment: @J.Doe *my teacher explained it to me* -- Forget about the code.  Draw a picture of the array, and the operations needed to insert a `0`.  Then write the code that mimics those operations.  You don't need a teacher's code to visualize what you need to do.  That is how you learn to write programs -- visualize in your mind, draw on paper, write the code.

Comment: Another issue with your code is that identation was not always correct and made me misunderstand it in a first step. Also follow advices from PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Unrelated comment: why did you finally accept the other answer and not mine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code, first of all your min is wrong. I have fixed your code with comments on fixes I have made. Please take a look :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int min = 10000;
    bool found = 0;
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of elements (n): "; //no of elements in the 
    std::cin >> n;                                     //array

    int *array = new int[2 * n];

    std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> array[i];
        if (array[i] < min) //< instead of >
            min = array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        if (array[i] == min) 
        {                  
            for (int k = n; k > i; k--)
            {
                array[k] = array[k - 1];
            }
            array[i + 1] = 0;               
            i++; //increment i here because you don't want to consider 0 that you have just added above.                           
            n++; //since total number of elements in the array has increased by one (because of 0 that we added), we need to increment n
        }
    }

    //print the array separately 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << array[i];
        if (i != n - 1)
        {
            std::cout << ",";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue was in the calculation of `min`: `<` instead of `>`.

Another problem if that you are modifyng the paramers `i`and `n`inside the loop. This is rather dangerous and implies to be very cautious.

Another issue was that it should be `i++; n++;` instead of `i--,n--;`

Here  is the code:

```
//  #include <pch.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    int min = 1000000;
    int n;                                       
    std::cout << "Enter the number of elements (n): "; //no of elements in the 
    std::cin >> n;                                     //array

    int *array = new int[2 * n];

    std::cout << "Enter the elements" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                      
        std::cin >> array[i];
        if (array[i] < min)
            min = array[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                
        if (array[i] == min) {                   // Not very clear about this
            for (int k = n; k > i; k--)          // part of the code, my teacher
                 array[k] = array[k - 1];        //explained it to me , but i 
            array[i + 1] = 0;               // didn't understand (from the)      
            i++;
            n++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {                
        std::cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```